# OpenGL what does glTexImage2D do?

Tags: opengl

What does `gl.glTexImage2D` do? The docs say it "uploads texture data". But does this mean the whole image is in GPU memory? I'd like to use one large image file for texture mapping. Further: can I simply use a VBO for uv and position coordinates to draw the texture?

Right, I am using words the wrong way here. What I meant was carrying a 2D array of UV coordinates and a 2D array of model to subsample a larger PNG image (in texture memory) onto individual tile models. My confusion here lies in not knowing how fast these fetches can take. Lets say I have a 5000x5000 pixel image. I load it as a texture. Then I create my own algorithm for fetching portions of it to draw. Where do I save myself the bandwidth for drawing these tiles? If I implement an LOD algorithm to determine which tiles are close, which are far and which are out of the camera frustum how do manage each these tiles in memory? Loaded question I know but I am struggling to find the best implementation to get started. I am developing for mobile devices with OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 11):

What exactly happens when you call `glTexImage2D()` is system dependent, and there's no way for you to know, unless you have developer tools that allow you to track GPU and memory usage.

The only thing guaranteed is that the data you pass to the call has been consumed by the time the call returns (since the API definition allows you to modify/free the data after the call), and that the data is accessible to the GPU when it's used for rendering. Between that, anything is fair game. Keep in mind that OpenGL is a very asynchronous API. When you make API calls, the corresponding work is mostly queued up for later execution by the GPU, and is generally not completed by the time the calls return. This can include calls for uploading data.

Also, not all GPUs have "GPU memory". In fact, if you look at them by quantity, very few of them do. Mobile GPUs have caches, but mostly not VRAM in the sense of traditional discrete GPUs. How VRAM and caches are managed is highly system dependent.

With all the caveats above, and picturing a GPU that has VRAM: While it's possible that they can load the data into VRAM in the `glTexImage2D()` call, I would be surprised if that was commonly done. It just wouldn't make much sense to me. When a texture is loaded, you have no idea how soon it will be used for rendering. Since you don't know if all textures will fit in VRAM (and they often will not), you might have to evict it from VRAM before it was ever used. Which would obviously be very wasteful. As a general strategy, I think it will be much more efficient to load the texture data into VRAM only when you have a draw call that uses it.

Things would be somewhat different if the driver could be very confident that all texture data will fit in VRAM. But with OpenGL, there's really no reasonable way to know this ahead of time. And things get even more complicated since at least on desktop computers, you can have multiple applications running at the same time, while VRAM is a shared resource.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct.

glteximage2d is the function that actually moves the texture data across to the gpu.

you will need to create the texture object first using glGenTextures() and then bind it using glBindTexture().

there is a good example of this process in the opengl redbook 
[example](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html)

you can then use this texture with a VBO. There are many ways to accomplish this, but interleaving your vertex coordinates, texture coordinates, and vertex normals and then telling the GPU how to unpack them with several calls to glVertexAttribPointer is the best bet as far as performance.

you are on the right track with VBOs, the old fixed pipeline GL stuff is depricated so you should just learn VBO from the outset.

this book is not 100% up to date, but it is complete and free and should serve as a great place to start learning VBO [Open GL Book](http://openglbook.com/the-book.html)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I want to use one big png file representing terrain. To complement this timage i also have a grid of height values at a slightly coarser detail. My thought was to break the texture it into tiles using a texture mapping scheme. Is this the general approach most people use for rendering large terrain scenes? Thanks!

Comment: @Fra: Texture mapping is not breaking things down into tiles. Having said that, the bleeding-edge technology is to go the other way round, i.e. merge lots of small texture tiles into one large (sparse) texture. Modern GPUs have memory management units and can fetch required portions of textures from CPU memory when needed and swap out the not required parts on demand. However you need a fairly recent GPU (2012-ish or later) for this to be supported. If you want to tile down a large image into smaller tiles, every tile must become an individual texture, or you use a 2D texture array.

Comment: @Fra: What you are describing could be one of two things. if you are talking about saving draw time by keeping multiple levels of detail within the same texture space, then MipMapping might be right for you. It creates multiple scaled copies of the image at image load time. If you are talking about more of a sprite based engine where a single texture sheet is used for multiple different images, then have your u,v mapping coords be generic and use uniform variables (glUniform) to select which tile should be drawn.

Comment: @Jonathan: well I am not entirely sure at this point. The area I want to render is about 15000x15000 colours. Seeing as how PNG files are very well compressed maybe it makes sense to first break the entire PNG int several textures based on the 4096x4096 max texture size for android. Then, when I want to draw, use UV coordinates within in each particular texture to drape the image over my mesh of X,Y,Z values. The only real way I can thin out my draw calls is simply to use less height values from my grid essentially right? Would just mean a coarser mesh.